# Why are lots of bubbles coming out of a freshly cut lotus stem?

Tags: plant-health

I cut some old lotus leafs, and there was one stem from which many bubbles got out. I started to worry when I realized that it had been minutes and minutes (I would say at least 10) since the bubbles were getting out of it at a pretty high outflow.

I was worried because I wondered from where does all this air came from, could it be from the roots (I heard that they are filled with air)? If this is the case, is it dangerous for the plant to have water on its roots?

Comment: Please clarify exactly which plant you mean - lotus is a name used for several plants.

Comment: @Bamboo Well... a lotus like that : http://www.latour-marliac.com/img/guide-lotus.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Nelumbo nucifera then - the long stems on this plant contain air spaces to maintain buoyancy - you've obviously cut one that wasn't quite dead, and the air bubbles are coming out of the still live stem, possibly with some sap as well. Nothing you can do about it - it'll stop eventually.

Comment: I'd never thought about HOW water plants stayed on the top of the water!  Way cool, Bamboo!

Comment: @stormy - I'm probably much older than you and been in the horticultural trade for 40 years - I quite wish I was cool though!